# DOS Batch Create Folders under multiple directories

Tags: batch-file, dos

I'm currently learning DOS and I am trying to better organize some of my client directories. I want to create 5 folders (2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, & 2015) under each of my clients' folders, but I have a lot of clients and want to do so with a batch command.

Here's an example of my directory now:

C:\Clients\Name\

Here's what I want to do:

C:\Clients\Name\2015

I have roughly 200 different clients so individually creating these will be tedious and time consuming. Is there a way to write to all of the 'Name' folders even though they are all different?

Comment: "I'm currently learning DOS" Wow, that sentence triggered some big nostalgic feelings in me. So if I'm right you're looking for a command to copy a file to multiple directories at once, or do you want to create the directories? Apart from that, are you running Windows 95 or some Windows version that has Power-shell installed?

Comment: Are you **really** learning "DOS"? Or are you referring to the command line in Windows? Because that is something completely different

Comment: Have qbasic with these Dos ? Then have it create your batch file for you. How will the client names look like ? Real names or consecutive numbers ? I guess they already exist ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pushd C:\Clients
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    for %%i in (2011 2012 2013 2014 2015) do mkdir %%d\%%i
)
popd
```

Comment: That wouldn't work in "DOS" (although I'm pretty sure Jox is referring to the Windows command line, not "DOS")

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch file that could do the trick:
You can run it in 2 ways:

- pass the folder (e.g. *C:\Clients*) as an argument
- go to the folder (`cd C:\Clients`) and run it from there with no argument

**Note**: It also works for folders that contain *SPACE* s, and YES this is *cmd* specific (not *DOS*)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

if "" neq "%~1" (
    if exist "%~1\" (
        set WORK_DIR="%~1"
    ) else (
        set WORK_DIR="%CD:"=%"
    )
) else (
    set WORK_DIR="%CD:"=%"
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a:d %WORK_DIR%') do (
    for %%g in (2011 2012 2013 2014 2015) do (
        mkdir "%WORK_DIR:"=%\%%f\%%g"
    )
)
```